# Can we use requestlocationupdate in timertask?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

A timertask class is called every five minutes inside I have to use

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(Utils.googleApiClient, 
mlocationrequest, this);
```

to find location and stores the location in DB using onLocationChanged().

How to implement this? Please help me I tried but it is not working.

Comment: You can use min interval on LocationRequest object for min of 5 min

Comment: Need to take location even after the app is closed until app is uninstalled. So I need to use timertask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates on timertask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625444/how-to-use-fusedlocationapi-requestlocationupdates-on-timertask)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below code, you will get location `onLocationChanged()` by MIN_TIME and MIN_DISTANCE 
- MIN_TIME: minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds 
- MIN_DISTANCE: minimum distance between location updates, in meters

```
 LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, TIME_OFFSET, MIN_DISTANCE, new android.location.LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    onUpdateLocation(location);
                    Log.e("update location", location.getLatitude() + "------" + location.getLongitude());
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }
            });
        }
```